# Angular httpClient interceptor error handling

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient

after reading the documentation on angular about http client error handling, I still don't understand why I don't catch a 401 error from the server with the code below:

```
export class interceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log('this log is printed on the console!');

        return next.handle(request).do(() => (err: any) => {
            console.log('this log isn't');
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                if (err.status === 401) {
                    console.log('nor this one!');
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

on the console log, I also get this:

> zone.js:2969 GET http://localhost:8080/test 401 ()
>
> core.js:1449 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/test", ok: false, …}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should catch an error using `catchError`

```
return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(catchError(err => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                console.log('this should print your error!', err.error);
            }
        }
}));
```

Comment: Read more about it here https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details

Comment: I get this error: TS2345: Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.

Comment: I just mentioned the syntax for catching errors. You should return the error or properly handle it in there. for ex you can do `return Observable.throw(err);` You could also change your return type to `Observable<any>` instead of `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`

Comment: What should be the correct return result if I just want "nothing to happen" (ie, it wasn't an error) ?

Comment: I tried adding `return Observable.empty<HttpEvent<any>>()`, but I still get a ' EmptyError: no elements in sequence' printed in the console

Comment: If you don't want to throw any error, then simply return Observable.empty() or Observable.of(false)

Comment: When using a Observable.empty(), I still get a 'GET http://localhost:8080/test 403 ()' log in my console log.How can I avoid it?

Comment: Though it feels this is normal behaviour. Although I still get a EmptyError: no elements in sequence when I load the page. Where can it come from ?

Comment: I'll create a new question and close this one then, thanks. ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002928/rxjs-emptyerror-no-elements-in-sequence

Comment: `Observable.empty()` is deprecated. Your error handler must to return a `new Observable<HttpEvent<any>>()` instead

Answer (score 12):

Your error handler needs to return a `new Observable<HttpEvent<any>>()`

```
return next.handle(request)
    .pipe(catchError((err: any) => {
        console.log('this log isn't');
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                console.log('Unauthorized');
            }
        }

      return new Observable<HttpEvent<any>>();
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the argument value to the do function of the stream, not create a new function inside it:

```
return next.handle(request)
    .do((err: any) => {
        console.log('this log isn't');
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            if (err.status === 401) {
                console.log('nor this one!');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I still don't get the 'nor this one' log.

Comment: Add a debugger inside the do, check what is the response that comes from the server and check why is not matching the two ifs.

Answer (score 0):

It is off top, but Angular has better opportunity handle errors than interceptor.
You can implement your own ErrorHandler.
https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler

Comment: [When someone goes on Stack Exchange, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/171858).

Comment: It is the answer. Move to off Angular documentation, not only copy-paste.@ErikPhilips

Comment: How to implement it for handling network errors? The documentation doesn't has much for specific use case @Oleksii

Answer (score 0):

here some example I'm using:

```
export class ErrorHandlerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(
        request: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const loadingHandlerService = this.inej.get(LoadingHandlerService);
        const errorHandlerService = this.inej.get(ErrorHandlerService);

        return next.handle(request)
            .pipe(
                catchError(err => {
                    loadingHandlerService.hideLoading();
                    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) { errorHandlerService.handleError(err) }
                    return new Observable<HttpEvent<any>>();
                })
            );
    }

    constructor(private inej: Injector) { }
}
```